# How to detect which site is being displayed in the TikTok app's proprietary browser?

Tags: browser, internet, url, tiktok

**I am looking for a way to find out the address of a website that is being opened in the integrated (proprietary) browser of the TikTok application.**

I am trying to stop some fraudulent visits to our website through Google ads. We have reported these videos for a month on TikTok, but they are still active. We have contacted Google Ads customer support, and they say it's not their responsibility. Google hides the HTTP_REFERRER in the clicks that come through Google Ads, and our server only receives a client ID "gclid" and Google as the referrer.

**The modus operandi is as follows:**

The attacker runs an ad campaign on TikTok with videos offering fake jobs with very high salaries, no experience required, and excellent conditions (impossible ones, to be clear). Just to attract visits. At the end of the video, the ad says "swipe left" ... there, a page opens containing only links to Google Ads' paid ads. Because this page opens in TikTok's browser, no information about the website (the page) being displayed can be found.

**This is causing a triple harm:**

1. Fraudulent clicks that we paid for.
2. Annoyance from calls (60-100/every day) regarding the fake job offers.
3. It seems the attacker is paid by Google Adsense when someone clicks from their page.

**Any solution ideas will be welcomed.
Thank you.**